# azure blob parallel blob deleting

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I want to fast delete many blobs from azure storage. Azure method for delete blob is awaitable. I have more than 1000 blobs to delete. My question is if it is faster to delete blobs in parallel, for example in 20 parallel tasks?

Comment: It is certainly possible to do so. Please tell us what you have tried so far (show us the code) and what issues you're running into.

Comment: it is faster, but azure can be throttled

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.blobs.batch-readme